# PdfLatex crops the image while converting

Tags: pdftex, conversion, eps, crop

I'm using pdfLaTeX, Vim and LaTeX suite on Ubuntu, with the `graphics` package.
  I've exported an image from Matlab to EPS format, but the automatic conversion (I'm not sure what converts it to pdf) crops some of the image.

[image: Converted]

The EPS file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9IrHGxp_N3aVU1kVDFYcEVBZDQ)

Tweaking with Matlab's export or LaTeX's `\includegraphics` parameters didn't help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[width=3.5in]{im1.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

TIA!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please show us the shortend TeX code you used to show us the effect.  Make the TeX code compilable!

Comment: The image of the question, annotated with "converted", does not show any cropping of the linked `im1.eps`. All elements of the graphics are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely, the bounding box data in the EPS file are wrong. Ghostscript can be used to calculate the bounding box, e.g. (replace `tiger.eps` by your file`):

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE tiger.eps
```

The result is something like:

```ps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 150977 150977
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 150976.921393 150976.939393
```

These lines can be used to replace the line starting with `%%BoundingBox:` at the start section of the EPS file.

The "automatic conversion" in LaTeX uses `epstopdf` (LaTeX package that calls the Perl script with the same name) for the conversion and uses the bounding box data as media size of the generated PDF file.

---

The method works for the EPS file `im1.eps` of the updated [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/349021/5), the bounding box reported by ghostscript:

```ps
%%BoundingBox: 23 20 381 293
%%HiResBoundingBox: 23.201999 20.519999 380.603660 292.103640
```

After editing `im1.eps`, the starting comment section of the EPS file looks like:

```ps
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%CreationDate: 2017-01-16T20:11:08
%%Pages: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 23 20 381 293
%%HiResBoundingBox: 23.201999 20.519999 380.603660 292.103640
%%LanguageLevel: 3
%%EndComments
```

BTW, the original bounding box is `0 0 500 500`. Since the real bounding box
is smaller, the converted PDF file has additional white margins, if the EPS file is not fixed.

There is another way to fix the image:

```
epstopdf im1.eps
pdfcrop im1.pdf
```

The result is `im1-crop.pdf`, which is included in the LaTeX document:

```
\includegraphics{im1-crop}
```

---

`im1.eps` is the file from the question, `im2.eps` is the EPS file with fixed bounding box. Then the following document for `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{im1}}
\par
\bigskip
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{im2}}
\end{document}
```

generates

> [image: Result]

The frames, generated by `\fbox` visualize the bounding boxes. The result shows that the original image has large white margins and the corrected image has a tight bounding box.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work on my machine. I changed the beginning of the eps file exactly like you did, and also tried the epstopdf/pdfcrop method- but both seem to produce the same erroneus image above.
Tool versions: GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
and epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 36129 2015-01-24 00:30:11Z karl $) 2.23

Comment: @Danny Your `im1.eps` does not have any other text then the numbers for the axis ticks and the label "x" for the vertical axis. Images of previous question versions also show other text elements. Therefore, your `im1.eps` is the wrong image, export it from Matlab and review the EPS file with a PostScript viewer (e.g. `gv`) that the export was correct.

Comment: I checked with gv and Matlab like you said- it looks fine. I'm sorry for the confusion, I did change the files, but it should be OK no matter which version you're using- all I did was to change the bounding box a little. Bottom line is that on my machine the bounding box doesn't help- does it solve the problem on yours?

Comment: @Danny Both methods of my answer worked for me without problems. Check the `.log` file, which files are actually included. The automatically generated file is named `im1-eps-converted-to.pdf`. Delete it and let it regenerate by the next run of `pdflatex` for the case there is something wrong with the file dates.

Comment: Everything seems fine, I think maybe we're using slightly different tools. If you compile the original file (without the fix) to pdf, is it cropped? Maybe I should update the tools?

Comment: @Danny I doubt that there is much difference in the tools. Since the information of the question (versions, description) is inconsistent with `im1.eps`, please, review the questions and steps of image generation: Original image of Matlab (e.g. screenshot), the exported image `im1.eps` (check with a PostScript viewer like `gv`), the automatically generated image `im1-eps-conterted-to.pdf` (check with PDF viewer). Also control the `.log` file that the correct image at the correct location is included.

Comment: Hi Heiko, thank you so much for the help. I double checked, it is consistent and the problem persists on my side. I believe its a local issue, since it doesn't seem to reproduce on other machines. But your answer was definitely valuable and assisting.

Comment: Heiko, hi again, I just found out that the problem was actually the pdf viewer! Ubuntu's Document Viewer. Switching to another viewer on the same file solved the problem.